# Dart/Flutter: Method 'foldIndexed' isn't defined for the type 'List'

Tags: list, flutter, dart, fold

I am trying to use the `foldIndexed()` method on a `List` in **Flutter/Dart**, like so:

```
// should only compute the combined character length of the first two fruits
['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'].foldIndexed(
    0,
    (index, previousElement, element) =>
        index < 2 ? previousElement + element.length : previousElement);
```

For some reason it shows the following syntax error: `The method 'foldIndexed' isn't defined for the type 'List'.`

From this [**documentation**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/foldIndexed.html) I understand that `foldIndexed()` is part of Flutter and that it should be possible to use it on a `List` as `List` is an implementation of the `Iterable` abstract class.

Any ideas why Flutter casts the above mentioned error or won't let me use it? Or is there **another way of getting access to the iteration index** when using the `fold()` method on a `List`?

Comment: you need to import `collection.dart`

Comment: ah, I see thank you!

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My problem was that I had forgotten to import `collection.dart` as pointed out by @pskink.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't obvious to me, so I had to look further for how to use it. I found the answer with https://www.perplexity.ai:

To use `foldIndexed` in a list in Flutter, you need to use the IterableExtension extension from the collection library ([docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/foldIndexed.html)). Here is an example of how to use `foldIndexed` on a list of strings:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  final fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'];
  final combinedLength = fruits.foldIndexed(
    0,
    (index, previousElement, element) =>
        index < 2 ? previousElement + element.length : previousElement,
  );
  print(combinedLength); // Output: 10
}
```